Using vImageFloodFill_ARGB8888 on iOS to create a Flood fill for a UIImage
Using the Accelerate framework which I don't really fully comprehend if I am honest, I am trying to create a flood fill for a UIImage. I have a UIImage extension but the result I get is unpredictable if the image is of anything. If the UIImage is a single color image where every pixel is identical then the result is as expected but if I take an image from my camera roll and attempt to run floodFill I get a mess.
This is the code I'm working with:
import Accelerate
import Accelerate.vImage
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics


extension UIImage {
    
  func floodFill(seedPoint: CGPoint, replacementColor: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
        guard var buffer = self.toVImage() else {
            return nil
        }
               
        guard var maskBuffer = createMaskBuffer(width: Int(buffer.width), height: Int(buffer.height)) else {
            return nil
        }

        let replacementRGBA = replacementColor.toRGBA()
       
       var cgImageFormatPlanarF = vImage_CGImageFormat(
           bitsPerComponent: 32,
           bitsPerPixel: 32,
           colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(),
           bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(
               rawValue: kCGBitmapByteOrder32Host.rawValue |
               CGBitmapInfo.floatComponents.rawValue |
               CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue),
           renderingIntent: .defaultIntent)!
       
       let bufferPlanarF = try! vImage.PixelBuffer<vImage.PlanarF>(
        cgImage: self.cgImage!,
           cgImageFormat: &cgImageFormatPlanarF)
        bufferPlanarF.colorThreshold(
            0.5,
           destination: bufferPlanarF)
       let bufferRGB8 = vImage.PixelBuffer<vImage.Interleaved8x4>(
           planarBuffers: [bufferPlanarF, bufferPlanarF, bufferPlanarF, bufferPlanarF])
       
        // Create a contiguous memory block for RGBA components
        var rgbaComponents: [UInt8] = [replacementRGBA.0, replacementRGBA.1, replacementRGBA.2, replacementRGBA.3]

       bufferRGB8.withUnsafePointerToVImageBuffer { src in
           vImageFloodFill_ARGB8888(src, nil,
                                    UInt(seedPoint.x), UInt(seedPoint.y),
                                    &rgbaComponents, 8, 0)
           
       }
 

        
       let cgImageFormatRGB8 = vImage_CGImageFormat(
           bitsPerComponent: 8,
           bitsPerPixel: 8 * 4,
           colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
           bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(
               rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue),
           renderingIntent: .defaultIntent)!
       
       guard let result = bufferRGB8.makeCGImage(cgImageFormat: cgImageFormatRGB8) else{
           return nil
       }
       return UIImage(cgImage: result)
    }
    
    private func toVImage() -> vImage_Buffer? {
        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else {
            return nil
        }
        
        guard let colorSpace = cgImage.colorSpace else {
            return nil
        }
        
        var format = vImage_CGImageFormat(bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                       bitsPerPixel: 8 * 4,
                                       colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                                       bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast.rawValue))!
        
        var buffer = vImage_Buffer()
        
        let error = vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage(&buffer, &format, nil, cgImage, vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))
        
        guard error == kvImageNoError else {
            print("Error creating vImage buffer: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
        
        return buffer
    }


    private func vImageToCGImage(buffer: vImage_Buffer) -> CGImage? {

        guard let context = CGContext(data: buffer.data,
                                      width: Int(buffer.width),
                                      height: Int(buffer.height),
                                      bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                      bytesPerRow: buffer.rowBytes,
                                      space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                                      bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue).rawValue) else {
            return nil
        }

        return context.makeImage()
    }
    
    private func createMaskBuffer(width: Int, height: Int) -> vImage_Buffer? {

        let bytesPerPixel = 4
        let bytesPerRow = width * bytesPerPixel
        let byteCount = bytesPerRow * height
        let maskData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: byteCount)
        

        var maskBuffer = vImage_Buffer(data: maskData, height: vImagePixelCount(height), width: vImagePixelCount(width), rowBytes: bytesPerRow)

        memset(maskBuffer.data, 0, byteCount)
        
        return maskBuffer
    }
    
}

extension UIColor {
    func toRGBA() -> (UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8) {
        var red: CGFloat = 0, green: CGFloat = 0, blue: CGFloat = 0, alpha: CGFloat = 0
        getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
        
        return (UInt8(red * 255), UInt8(green * 255), UInt8(blue * 255), UInt8(alpha * 255))
    }
}

I have tried several approaches to passing the replacement color. Am I trying to do something impossible?
The vImageFloodFill_ARGB8888 flood fill function not designed to be an actual flood fill but only to fill empty images.
Edit:

I edited the post to add an image of the results.
I have also edited the code block to show what I am using which is based directly on the Apple documentation for this.

Include the input and output current "messy" picture, it will be way easier to troubleshoot.

I figured out why the image is messy the wrong colorspace data was being sent when converting the image from a CGImage to a vImage. Now the flood fill just doesn't have an adjustable threshold for how much to fill when pixels aren't identicle
